# ASP.NET MVC 5 DropDownList Post Selected Value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Index.cshtml - View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Kayit", "HaberEkle", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success"}))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.HaberKategori)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.HaberKategori, Model.HaberKategori, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
}
```

HaberEkleContoller.cs - ResultPage

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var HaberEkleModel = new HaberEkle();
    HaberEkleModel.HaberKategori = (from c in DBModel.HaberKategori
                                    select new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Selected = false,
                                        Text = c.KategoriAdi,
                                        Value = c.KategoriID.ToString()
                                    }).ToList();
    return View(HaberEkleModel);
}
```

HaberEkleController.cs - Controller Page

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Kayit(HaberEkle modelyakala)
{
    // i want post my data.
    var PostedData = "";
    ViewBag.KategoriAdi = PostedData;
    return View();
}
```

HaberEkle.cs - Model Page

```
public class HaberEkle
{
    [Display(Name="Haber Başlık")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Lütfen Haber Başlığı Giriniz.")]
    [MaxLength(50,ErrorMessage="Haber Başlığı Maksimum 50 Karakter Olabilir.")]
    public string HaberBaslik { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Haber İçerik")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Lütfen Haber İçeriği Giriniz.")]
    public string HaberIcerik { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Durum")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Lütfen Haber Durumu Seçiniz.")]
    public List<SelectListItem> HaberDurum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Kategori")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Lütfen Kategori Seçiniz.")]
    public List<SelectListItem> HaberKategori { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFile HaberFoto { get; set; }
}
```

How can I post my dropdownlist get the selected value?

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (whicj is what your `List<SelectListItem> HaberKategori` property is. Your model needs a property to bind to, e.g. `public int SelectedHaberKategori { get; set; }` and the view code is `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedHaberKategori, Model.HaberKategori)` (and you apply the attributes to `SelectedHaberKategori`, not `HaberKategori`)

Comment: i added ActionResult Page please check my dropdownlist.

Comment: i will writing code.

Comment: That fine, although there is not point setting `Selected = false,` (its just ignored anyway). You need to read my last comnent.

Comment: Mr Stephen Thanks For Help.

My code is working know :)